# Change input box placeholder upon select box option change using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created an input box where the placeholder changes if the selected option of the select box is changed. Please have a look at the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dL2aqckj/2/

This is the html:

```
<select id="selector">
<option value="book">Book</option>
<option value="journal">Journal</option>
<option value="newspaper">Newspaper</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="searchbox" placeholder="Find Book" size="20">
```

and this the JavaScript:

```
var selector = $("#selector");
var searchbox = $("#searchbox");

selector.on("change", function () {

  searchbox.attr('placeholder', "Find " + selector.find(':selected').text()
)});
```

This all works nicely. Now I want the placeholder to contain a custom text and not just the name of the select box option. Therefore I am trying to match the select box selected option with some placeholder text. This is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2x5m746e/1/

The JavaScript code:

```
var placeholderText = {
    "book": "Enter book ID",
    "journal": "Enter journal ID",
    "newspaper": "Enter newspaper ID",
};

var selector = $("#selector");    
var searchbox = $("#searchbox");  

selector.on("change", function () {

  searchbox.attr('placeholder', searchbox.val(placeholderText[selector.find(':selected').text()])
)});
```

It does not change the placeholder correctly. What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your keys in your `placeholderText` object are `book`, `journal` & `newspaper` you want to get `placeholderText['book']` or `placeholderText['journal']` for instance.

So you should get the value not the text of the selected item since in your HTML code your values in options are `book`, `journal` & `newspaper`.

```js
var placeholderText = {
   "book": "Enter book ID",
    "journal": "Enter journal ID",
    "newspaper": "Enter newspaper ID",
};

$("#selector").on("change", function () {
  $("#searchbox").attr('placeholder', placeholderText[$(this).find(':selected').val()]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selector">
  <option value="book">Book</option>
  <option value="journal">Journal</option>
  <option value="newspaper">Newspaper</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchbox"  placeholder="Enter book ID" size="20">
```